# ¿Cómo tener tres instancias de un JTable?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo un `JTable` en la interface `JFrame`.

Quisiera tres intancias para no tener que crear tres `JTable` en mi `JFrame`, teniendo 3 radio buttons y que cada uno de ellos tenga una instancia.

Quiero poner datos diferentes y que cada radio button guarde su datos con la instancia correspondiente.

Añado seudocódigo de lo que necesito implementar:

```
if(radiobutton1.setselected(true))
{
  jtable tabla1 = new jtable();
  tabla1.visible();
}

if(radiobutton2.setselected(true))
{
  jtable tabla2 = new jtable();
  tabla2.visible();
}

if(radiobutton3.setselected(true))
{
  jtable tabla3 = new jtable();
  tabla3.visible();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te he entendido.

Si quieres crear comportamientos diferentes de un objeto, lo más fácil es crearte una variable "global" (atributo) de ese objeto y darle la funcionaldad.

Ejemplo (Lo hago con objetos simulando tu JTable):

```
package ferpaxecosanxez;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class VariableGlobal {
    // Variable "global".
    private static List<Object> objetos;// Sería tu JTable.

    /**
     * En este caso es el main, pero en tu caso lo pones dentro
     * del método que tu desees realizar la selección y verificación
     * del resultado de los radio button.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Opciones posibles, pasarían a ser tus radio button.
        Integer botonUno = 1;
        Integer botonDos = 2;
        Integer botonTres = 3;

        /* 
         * Cuando llames al método con cada una de las opciones
         * el resultado será distinto, en tu caso, tu JTable será
         * y tendrá diferentes datos.
         * Ya vas probando...
         */
        VariableGlobal.accionQueSeRealiza(botonTres);
    }


    /**
     * Método que realiza una acción en concreto en función
     * del valor de selección de los radio button.<br>
     * Lo hacemos static por facilidad de código.
     * @param opcion En tu caso, es valor obtenido desde los
     * radio button.
     */
    public static void accionQueSeRealiza(Integer opcion){
        /*
         * Para obtener el dato de tus radio button, debería de existir
         * un método parecido a: varDeRadioButtonN.getSelected().
         */
        switch (opcion) {
        // En tu caso varDeRadioButtonUno.getSelected() = true
        case 1:
            // Generas tu JTable que en mi caso es un List<>.
            objetos = new ArrayList<Object>();
            /*
             * Si es la opción uno, que agrege dos objetos por ejemplo.
             * En tu caso, que tu JTable tenga 4 campos o lo 1o que desees.
             */
            objetos.add(new String("Objeto Uno de opción uno"));
            objetos.add(new Integer(1990));

            for (Object obj : objetos) {
                System.out.println(obj);
            }
            break;

        // En tu caso varDeRadioButtonDos.getSelected() = true
        case 2:
            // Otra comportamiento, en mi caso, un solo objeto.
            objetos = new ArrayList<Object>();
            objetos.add(new Double(20D));

            for (Object obj : objetos) {
                System.out.println(obj);
            }
            break;

        // En tu caso varDeRadioButtonTres.getSelected() = true
        case 3:
            objetos = new ArrayList<Object>();
            objetos.add(new Date());

            for (Object obj : objetos) {
                System.out.println(obj);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te ayude, pero la idea es esa.

Comment: gracias ya capte la idea